# Guidance regarding probability

Tags: probability, reference-request

Does anyone know any good problems collection for elementary probability to be used along with Stirzaker ?
I currently have Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability by Mosteller, but that is not sufficient practice.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have the Mosteller collection, but some of those problems are more about clever tricks than actually practicing solving probability problems.

This one is like a collection for job interviews.
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135A/resources/chpr.pdf

Pretty easy yet instructive exercises.

[Probability Through Problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038795063X) by Marek Capinski

I used this to help me through a class.

[One Thousand Exercises in Probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198572212)